# Is that a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

The code allocates a memory for "p" variable but I think it can't free it if there are no errors at moment of running this code. Am I right? Or it can free in somewhere else place of the program?

```
static NSVGparser* nsvg__createParser()
{
    NSVGparser* p;
    p = (NSVGparser*)malloc(sizeof(NSVGparser));
    if (p == NULL) goto error;
    memset(p, 0, sizeof(NSVGparser));

    p->image = (NSVGimage*)malloc(sizeof(NSVGimage));
    if (p->image == NULL) goto error;
    memset(p->image, 0, sizeof(NSVGimage));

    // Init style
    nsvg__xformIdentity(p->attr[0].xform);
    memset(p->attr[0].id, 0, sizeof p->attr[0].id);
    p->attr[0].fillColor = NSVG_RGB(0,0,0);
    p->attr[0].strokeColor = NSVG_RGB(0,0,0);
    p->attr[0].opacity = 1;
    p->attr[0].fillOpacity = 1;
    p->attr[0].strokeOpacity = 1;
    p->attr[0].stopOpacity = 1;
    p->attr[0].strokeWidth = 1;
    p->attr[0].strokeLineJoin = NSVG_JOIN_MITER;
    p->attr[0].strokeLineCap = NSVG_CAP_BUTT;
    p->attr[0].fillRule = NSVG_FILLRULE_NONZERO;
    p->attr[0].hasFill = 1;
    p->attr[0].visible = 1;

    return p;

error:
    if (p) {
        if (p->image) free(p->image);
        free(p);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The client code is expected to call the `nvsg_deleteParser()` function after using the returned parser in order to free its allocated resources:

```
NSVGparser *parser = nsvg__createParser();
if (parser)
{
    ...
    nvsg_deleteParser(parser);
}
```